# How to synchronize API Blueprint with API source code?

Tags: php, api, swagger, apiblueprint, raml

I want to develop an REST Full API using PHP. But before I develop the real API, I wanna create the Blueprint first as a documentation with the API console, let's say I'm using the swagger or raml to do it. As my understanding, the API Blueprint and the API are different source code. It's mean that if I changed the API, I also have to changed the API blueprint or vice versa.

What I want to know, is there any technologies/framework/code or anything to synchronize between the API and the API Blueprint?

Means that I only need to change in one side (in API or Blueprint) and than just do the synchronize to change the other side.

Many thanks.

Comment: have you looked into PhpDoc?

Comment: I think PhpDoc is only generate the documentation, what I want is like swagger, there is an API Console there so Me and My team can try the API using dummy data. - CMIIW

Comment: Then you'll most likely need to update 2 places

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately we (Apiary) do not actually offer any code synchronisation  tool at the moment for API Blueprint.

If you are looking for a way how to generate a description of your API from the code then API Blueprint isn't probably the best choice as we believe it should represent the contract between everybody involved in the API design lifecycle. This is also the reason why we have built the testing tool – Dredd – https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd

With Dredd you can test your API implementation is matching to your blueprint. It wouldn't make much sense if the blueprint would be generated from the implementation.

Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your statement that it wouldn't make sense if the blueprint would be generated from the implementation, because the implementation is refer to the blueprint.